# Where should css and js files be hosted?

Tags: css

I am developing a slider. The client ( a non-technical person ) wants a slider which he can use and distribute to people easily and other people non technical people can easily install it on their websites. I am ready with the slider but I am coming across a problem that where should I host all the core .css and .js files? If I try to host them on my clients hosting, how would the non-technical persons be able to use it without editing their html code?

I am looking for a solution in which the client just pastes a code into the website and the slider starts to work ( As he has been using widgets). Please help out. Thanks.

Comment: Create a scriptlet that loads all your components via ajax. That scriptlet can be pasted into the body of the website.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bandwidth, host them on your server.

Instead of having separate HTML and JS files, create all your HTML via JS (ie. `document.write(...)`), then your client only has to paste a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourdomain.com/widgets/slider.js"></script> <!-- Slider -->
```